# How to remove line that contain a certain string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a text file that looks like this

```
Big:house
small:door
Big:car
Small:chair
Big:plane
```

How to I remove the lines that contain the word "big" so it may look like this, I dont want to create a new file all together though

```
small:door
small:chair
```

Here was my attempt

```
with open('QWAS.txt','r') as oldfile:
for line in oldfile:
    if bad_words in line:
        newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: What if the line is `small:Big`, or `notbig:small`?

Comment: The easiest way is to read the whole file into memory (perhaps into a list using `file.readlines()`), make the adjustments there, and write the result back out to the file. If the file doesn't fit in memory, it becomes a bit more difficult. In that case it's much easier to create a new file.

Comment: @kindall could you show me an example, anything would be appreciated

Comment: Search "python edit file in place" and find the fileinput module.

Comment: @usr2564301 IOError: File not open for reading

Comment: Well there you go. If what you show here IS in fact all you wrote, that makes perfect sense. Do you have an idea what the error is telling you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what we can do:

1. Read data to string (remove rows that start with 'big')
2. Go to the start of file (seek)
3. Write the string
4. Truncate (remove overflow)

And now to the code, open it in read and write mode:

```
with open('QWAS.txt','r+') as f:
    data = ''.join([i for i in f if not i.lower().startswith('big')]) #1
    f.seek(0)                                                         #2
    f.write(data)                                                     #3
    f.truncate()                                                      #4
```

Comment: what if im grabbing something from a file like  myword = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)

Comment: @HellosAddme Sorry is this a new question or related?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newfile = r'output.txt'
oldfile = r'input.txt'


with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile, open(oldfile, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if if line[:5].lower() == 'small':
            outfile.write(line)

#output

small:door
Small:chair
```

Of course, this assumes you want to eliminate rows where small or Small is to the left of the colon. Additionally, you will have a new file output, as I don't think you really want to update your input file.

Comment: From the OP: "I dont want to create a new file all together though". Also, this will delete your file completely if you try to set `newfile` and `oldfile` to the same file!

Comment: remember you can use line[:5].lower() == 'small'

Comment: Good catch... that's better

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expressions

```
import re

oldfile = open('QWAS.txt','r')
newfile = open('newfile.txt','w')
for line in oldfile:
    if re.search('[Ss]mall',line):
        newfile.write(line)

oldfile.close()
newfile.close()
```

Which gives the output file "newfile.txt"

```
small:door
Small:chair
```

If you just take every line that doesn't have small and write it to a new file "newfile2.txt"

```
import re

oldfile = open('QWAS.txt','r')
newfile = open('newfile.txt','w')
newfile2 = open('newfile2.txt','w')

for line in oldfile:
    if re.search('[Ss]mall',line):
        newfile.write(line)
    else:
        newfile2.write(line)

oldfile.close()
newfile.close()
newfile2.close()
```

Comment: How do i just take every line that doesn't have small and write it to a new file